# Female Actor or Actress

Tags: grammatical-gender

I've recently noticed the word actor used for female actresses in the Indian print media.

I have a few questions :
 a) Is this the correct usage of the word?
 b) Is this an international phenomenon?
 c) Are you aware of the origins, time and purpose of this change?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/76147/14073

Answer (score 17, accepted):

a) It's correct to use the term "actor" for males and females

b) It's an international phenomenon

c) For origins and purpose of the change, see the [Wikipedia entry for actor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor#Terminology):

> The word actor refers to a person who acts regardless of gender, while actress refers specifically to a female person who acts; therefore a female can be referred to by either term. The Oxford English Dictionary states that originally "actor" was used for both sexes. The English word actress does not derive from the Latin actrix, probably not even by way of French actrice; according to the Oxford English Dictionary, **actress was "probably formed independently" in English**. As actress is a specifically feminine word, **some groups assert that the word is sexist**. Gender-neutral usage of actor has re-emerged in modern English, especially when referring to male and female performers collectively, but actress remains the common term used in major acting awards given to female recipients and is common in general usage.

Comment: Some with waiter/waitress, b.t.w.

Comment: There is a difference: a waiter and a waitress do the same jobs. You can't as easily substitute an actor with an actress. Not in most roles, anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the case in British English, possibly just yet.

Comment: @TRiG So would a doctor, teacher, police officer, child, bus driver, etc., etc. be played by an actor or an actress. There are **very many** roles where either could be used - so many that I'm not sure I would agree with your "most". (Written before I saw the answer from @UnbiasedOnlooker.)

Comment: @Wes [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=actor&title=21st) - a **British** dictionary defines "actor" as "a man or woman who performs in plays or films, especially as their profession."

Comment: Throughout history, characters that were originally one gender have been flipped to be a different gender in a later portrayal, and even played by someone of a differing gender in plays, films, and shows. Suggesting an actor can't be substituted with an "actress" is just plain wrong, as the history of performance has repeatedly shown.

Comment: @SEoF And even if that weren't the case, there is a long and storied history of performing in drag, for both sexes (although in different cultures)

Answer (score 5):

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/actor?q=actor) has the following footnote addressing this issue:

> In the time of Shakespeare female roles were played by boys or men, and women did not appear on stage in England until after the Restoration of 1660. Female performers were then called either **actors** or **actresses**—it was only later that actor became restricted to men—and it seems that we are returning to the original situation. Although there is still an awards category at the Oscars called Best Actress, some people are again using the gender-neutral term **actor** for both sexes.