# Should I use "authoress" for a feminine author?

Tags: grammatical-gender

Often I come across the term "female author" rather than "authoress". Which is the correct usage? "Female author" sounds wrong to me as other words that end in "-or" take a sex.

Comment: It's [grammatical gender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender). Sorry, no link for grammatical sex, because I don't want this comment to get flagged.

Comment: i too take it as old fashioned usage....there has been a lot of modifications made in the use of some words...

Comment: Just say "author".  Unless it is important to know the gender of the author, then say "female author" or "male author".

Comment: You know, in your question, "feminine author" doesn't have to be female. I'm just saying. :)

Comment: And as for "authoress," I see no point. But if you had a need to specify that the author of something was a woman, and you had a legitimate need to do it in immediate association with the term _author_, there would be nothing wrong with "female author."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term exists but it's considered "old-fashioned, sexist and patronising", as it says in my dictionary (NOAD):

> **-ess**: suffix. Forming nouns denoting female gender.
>
> - ORIGIN from French -esse, via late Latin from Greek -issa.
> - USAGE The suffix -ess has been used since the Middle Ages to form nouns denoting female persons, using a neutral or a male form as the base. [...] `In the late 20th century, as the role of women in society changed, some of these feminine forms became problematic and are now regarded as old-fashioned, sexist, and patronizing (e.g., poetess, authoress, editress)`. The ‘male’ form is increasingly being used as the ‘neutral’ form, where the gender of the person concerned is simply unspecified.

If you want a further reference also the OALD says the [same thing](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/authoress).

Comment: There is also a counter movement, which condemns the easy condemnation of perceived sexisms and keeps using them.

Comment: There's also a movement supporting using a single, specific noun instead of an adjective+noun. Most of the people in it don't realise it's a movement, though.

Comment: @RegDwight: I can't link it because it's the one built-in, but I've made a research and it uses the _New Oxford American Dictionary_. Is it ok or should I put a real link?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I think it's okay without a link (all I was saying was that the quote shouldn't be left completely unattributed).

Comment: Great. And yeah, I'll make sure to be specific on that too from now on.

Comment: Unsure about "editress." Last form I saw of that was "editrix." These are all basically obsolete. There is no reason to flag the gender of an author. Use "author."

Comment: @The Raven: I don't understand, are you supporting my answer or criticising some point? Because what you said (if I got it right) is more or less the point of my answer...

Comment: I use the term "authoress"- being a woman is a wonderful thing, why neuter them if the gender is known? The entries stating that the term is sexist, patronizing, etc., are using a tactic were just by saying that this is the case, people start perceiving it that way. I've never had an issue with it throughout college.

Comment: @DKelly Well, I'm not the one who neuters nouns. As far as I know, what the dictionary states is usually the current situation defined by users. So if the dictionary says that a term is rare, it means that usually the speakers don't use it. Now, my current dictionary says nothing about it being sexist, etc., it's possible that its use is changing through time. :) Feel free to link me sources on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say both are acceptable, though *female author* is probably more common. *Authoress* is now a bit old fashioned, I believe; it evokes a hint of romance and high literature to me, often in an ironic sense. In most cases, there is no need to express the sex of an author outside the use of pronouns (*U.G. Liness uses this technique in her latest novel...*): most people would simply use *author* for either sex.

I think *gender* is a bit more modern than *sex*, but, again, both are fine and quite common. In grammar, however, it is now nearly always *gender*.

Comment: Has it ever been "grammatical sex"? I'm genuinely curious

Comment: @NoName: I thought so, but I'm not sure now.

Answer (score 0):

This is surely the same as the [Female Actor or Actress question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3349/3752).

If you **must** specify the sex of the writer, then either is OK as far as I can see (although "authoress" probably sounds quite old-fashioned to most people in a way in which "actress" doesn't). On the other hand if whether or not the person is female is not a significant issue, then why not just stick with "author"?