# Fisherman/Fisherwoman and Gender-neutral Forms

Tags: grammatical-number, grammatical-gender, gender-neutral

What is the unisex form of a word like *fisherman*? Do you have to use *fisherman* and *fisherwoman* separately, or is *fisherperson* acceptable? I couldn’t find a dictionary with the word …

In general, what do you do when a word does not have a unisex form?

Comment: Rather than unisex, you'll have better luck in your search if you use _gender-neutral_.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not sure why you're concerned about the plural form before the singular has been sorted out :)

Comment: What's wrong with angler?

Comment: The gender-sensitive/ unisex concept to remember at all times is that *man* refers to *human being*, not *male*, in the context -- 'The Evolution of Man' does not exclude the feminine half of the species.

Comment: @Kris  Except that it does, subliminally.

Comment: @Mynamite Except it doesn't.

Comment: @ryan Well we could go on for hours saying 'yes it does' 'no it doesn't'. I think the continued lower status of women in most cultures suggests that it plays its part in sidelining them.

Comment: @ryan Anyway, I said 'subliminally', so how would you be aware of whether it does or not?

Comment: Very closely related: [A non-gendered word for fishermen](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247400/a-non-gendered-word-for-fishermen/247429#247429)

Comment: And he saith unto them, Follow me, and I will make you *fishers* of men.  Matthew 4:19, KJV

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**There really is no general rule.** Language evolves, and the evolution is primarily influenced by the people using the word, and different communities have different ways of thinking, so the “unisex” solutions turn out to be different for different words.

**There is a critical distinction to be drawn here between at least three kinds of gender-neutral language.**

- One is *grammatical* neutrality: this is easy in English but hard in many languages. For example, *moon* has no grammatical gender in English, but is feminine in French (*la lune*) and masculine in German (*der Mond*). Nevertheless, a few words in English sometimes take particular gender pronouns: *earth*, *moon*, and *nature*, for example, certain moral qualities (such as *wisdom* and *justice*), and certain forms of transportation (such as ships and automobiles), are sometimes feminine and take the pronoun *she*. You might describe this as personification. Another term for it, according to the Wikipedia article “[Gender in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_in_English)”, is *covert gender*.
- A second kind is *etymological* neutrality: language that contains no possible ambiguity, because it avoids root words that could be mistaken to mean only people who identify as a particular gender. In English, we rely more and more on such terms: *attendant*, *parenthood*, *letter carrier*, not *stewardess*, *motherhood*, *fatherhood*, *postman*.
- A third kind is *connotative* neutrality: language having grammatical or etymological roots in a gender, but nevertheless used and understood to connote nothing about gender: *manslaughter*, *freshman class*, *maiden voyage*, *master key*, *fraternal twins*, *lumberjack*, *matriculate*.

**In the fishing industry, the gender-neutral term actually used most is *fisherman*, plural *fishermen*.** The term is neutral in the first and third sense, but not the second. It is grammatically neutral, neutral in connotation, but not neutral in etymology, much like *freshman* and *lumberjack*.

There was a campaign in Canada to adopt the word *fisher*, but the women in the profession largely refused to have anything to do with it:

> [F]ederal efforts to replace *fisherman* with *fisher* in government documents, coupled with a high-profile Supreme Court decision on native fishing rights, caused a riptide of dissent over what to call people who fish. To complicate matters, many women in the industry didn’t want their job title changed and insisted on being called *fishermen*.[¹](http://www.btb.gc.ca/btb.php?lang=eng&cont=1724)

**It is certainly possible that the preference for *fisherman* as the gender-neutral term will diminish as time passes.**  Over the past thirty years, the use of many such words has become less common. As of this writing, *fisher* has not yet caught on in occupational or popular usage. Some academics and governmental agencies now use the term *fisher*, and this may eventually influence the public. See for example the conclusion of the recent Australian Broadcasting Corporation article, “[Is ‘fishermen’ a sexist and exclusionary term?](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-10-07/is-it-sexist-to-say-fishermen/7888986)” But only time will tell whether *fisher* really will catch on.

Comment: FWIW, I heard a female WNBA coach admonishing her female players to "Make sure you guard your **man**. We aren't playing zone defense here."

Comment: Nice answer. Definitely gives me something interesting to think about :)

Comment: There's a [WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-specific_job_title) that provides a nice overview of this ... situation.

Comment: @coleopterist Yes, I knew of chairperson, which is why this question came to mind :)

Comment: @asymptotically you mean the chairman?

Comment: @MetaEd, your accepted answer was suitable in 2012. Now five years later, at the cutting edge of language around gender, it is no longer enough to just say that it the accepted term is 'fisherman' has always been 'fisherman' and that even women in the industry prefer 'fisherman.' The question was: Is there a gender-neutral form of fisherman?

Comment: @WesModes I reviewed the answer, and it did seem to need updating. See what you think.

Comment: @metaed, thank you for your thoughtful addition. If I had to put money on it, I'd say Fisher will never catch on. I bet fisherman will be eventually replaced with fisherperson, a word that sounds strange in our mouths here in 2017. Yet we think nothing these days of serviceperson, salesperson, chairperson. For inspiration on that journey, we can look to what we might guess is a hopelessly gender-bound institution, the US Marines: https://www.monster.com/career-advice/article/marines-gender-neutral-job-titles

Comment: Actually, there is a gender neutral way of saying 'fisherman'.  'Fisher' - One of Beatrice Potter's stories for children is called "Jeremy Fisher".  We have footballers, golfers.  But MetaEd is basically correct.  It will take plain evolution to get to where we need to be.

Answer (score 8):

I have worked in the high seas commercial fishing industry my entire life. All the women I have met who fish for a living will admonish and correct you for calling them "fisherwoman".  We work hard for our title and that is Fisherman.

Comment: Genuinely curious question: Are you a fishermen yourself and do you think there is any possibility of internalized sexism in women preferring the term fisherman? Put another way, do you think the high demands of the occupation and its rep of being an exclusive fraternity means that, once accepted, women prefer to display their badge of entry into this fraternity?

Comment: The only time I ever heard the word “fischerwoman” was in theoretical discussions such as this one. I have never actually seen a person in my life referred to as a “fisherwoman”, always simply “fisherman” for either sex. I did not know the word even existed until I was 20 and when I first was apprised in a discussion such as this I was surprised that it was actually in dictionaries.

Answer (score 6):

*Man* has always been used in a gender-neutral way [per *Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/man). Until the arguably over-sensitive demands of feminism since the 1960s, words like *fisherman* or *chairman* were readily accepted as non-specific as to gender. As a result, the natural plural was the usual *men*. Continued use is therefore a matter of bravery!

Comment: Indeed so! The OED’s very first sense of *man* is “A human being (**irrespective of sex or age**); = L. *homo*. In OE. the prevailing sense.” Just so, the nearest relative to genus *Pan*, the chimpanzees and bonobos, is genus *Homo*, best translated as just plain ***man***, not as men and women. It’s like how an ombudsman can be a woman, or how in German “Mann sagt” doesn’t exclude women. If a *husbandman* is a farmer who tills the soil, they don’t turn into a **husbandwoman* just because they’re female. (Don’t misstep to the wrong etymon on *homosexual*, though: it’s not all about men. :)

Comment: It is true, but misleading, to say that "man" has always been used in a gender-neutral way. "Man" has been used in *both* a gender-neutral way *and* a gender-specific way since the late 13C when "wer" fell out of use.

Comment: @MetaEd I am happy to accept the correction.

Comment: I heard someone say it this way once: _"Remember, there are two kinds of man: there's male man, and female man_."

Comment: Editorialize much? Previous to those "over-sensitive demands of feminism" this kind of language squirreliness allowed our very language to reinforce a sexist status quo. Those demands of feminism have challenged language norms and moved us forward as a culture toward less exclusionary language.

Answer (score 3):

I think the use of the word "Angler" would be appropriate.

an•gler (ˈæŋ glər)

n.
1. a person who fishes with a hook and line

Comment: *Angling* is much more specific than *fishing*; I daresay most people who fish for a living do not do so by angling.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've adopted a term and have used it commonly for most of your life, it becomes normal, no matter how inappropriate or flawed it may be. Because you know and live it so commonly you don't really have to think about it... It just is...

So when you change it all of a sudden you have to think about it every time. You reference it and everything about whenever it's spoken or used in a document becomes thinking that wasn't needed before. That's very stressful and that's why people resist learning new ways of doing old things they've done all their lives. It causes stress. And who wants to stress out about something they never had to before?

It's better to leave it as is for the people accustomed to it and make the changes apply to new staff. The next generation of fishing professionals that now only know it the way that's correct.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I'm upvoting anyway because it's a very good point

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe nobody's given this answer, so I guess I will.  I'd just simply say "[fisher](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fisher)."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there’s a single definitive solution.

Most commonly, the suffix -*men* is used for the plural. The somewhat ungainly phrase “[*term*]men and women” (e.g., “fishermen and women”) can be used to make the inclusivity explicit.