# Looking for a gender neutral equivalent for "dairyman"

Tags: gender-neutral, professions

What would be the gender-neutral version of the term "dairyman"?

Comment: **dairyperson**

Comment: There is a closely related question “[Gender-neutral Forms](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/76147/14073)” that addresses gender neutral terms in general.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest "**dairy farmer**" if you mean the owner of the dairy farm. And "**dairy farm worker**" if you mean the general worker. These are the official occupations (at least in most of the English speaking countries)

Also, the business is called dairy farming.

> **[dairyman](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dairy+farmer):**
>
> > **1.** A man who owns or manages a dairy.
> >
> > **2.** A man who works in a dairy.
>
> **[dairy farmer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dairy+farmer):** the owner or manager of a dairy

---

There are even dairy farmers associations in different countries:

- [Dairy Farmers of Canada](http://www.dairyfarmers.ca/)
- [Dairy Farmers of America](http://www.dfamilk.com/)
- [Royal Association of British Dairy Farmers](http://www.rabdf.co.uk/)

---

Here is a list of dairy occupations (from the book "Modern Livestock & Poultry Production" *By James Gillespie, Frank Flanders*):
**Dairy Occupations**
Cheesemaker
 - cheese cooker
Dairy barnman
Dairy cattle herder
Dairy choreman
Dairy cow washer
Dairy farm worker
Dairy farmer
  - laborer, dairy farm
Dairy helper
Dairy herdsman
Dairy herd supervisor (DHIA)
Dairy management specialist
Dairy nutrition specialist
Dairy sanitarian
Dairy scientist
Dairy technologist
Dairy tester
Field contact technician, dairy
Manager, dairy farm
Milk plant supervisor
Milk sampler
Milker, machine
 - milking machine operator
 - sampler
Supervisor, dairy processing
 - butter production supervisor
 - cheese production

Comment: Dairy barman? That sounds cool!

Answer (score 1):

How about dairy worker or dairy keeper, depending upon the employment status of the individual concerned?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, consider:

**dairy hand**

**dairy helper**

**dairy operative**

**dairy peddler**

**dairy deliverer**

**dairy merchant**

**dairy dealer**

**dairy rancher**

and **dairy operator**