# Gender-neutral term for milkman

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

"Milkman" is a gendered term. I realise that having milk delivered every morning stopped being common before gender-neutral language started to become popular, but still, there must have been female people with that job at some point, and I'm wondering if a gender-neutral term was ever in use at any point.

I'm looking for a gender neutral term, rather than a specifically female one.

The reason is that I want to use a milkman as an illustrative example in an academic paper, so an example sentence would be something like

> Consider a _______ who has to deliver milk to n houses.

The idea of a milkman fits well with what I want to show, but I strive to make all my examples gender-neutral, so it bugs me that the term for this job is inherently gendered.

Words like courier or delivery driver won't work for me, because it's important that the thing being delivered is the same for every house, rather than an individual package with an address on it.

Comment: It’s not necessarily the same for every house. Quantities and sizes may differ, and there’s always cream. How about a newspaper route?

Comment: Also, the milkman picked up the empty glass bottles and returned them to the dairy to be reused. That’s part of the business model.

Comment: @Xanne I'm old enough to remember those things, but I'm not one to let little details like that get in the way of a good mathematical story. A paper round might work instead, I suppose.

Comment: The same applies to a newspaper round, doesn't it? You want a gender-neutral term for *paperboy.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach that's right, yes. Though for a paper round, "delivery person" would work, even if it's a bit awkward.

Comment: I wonder what name the moderns use for the "traveling salesman problem".

Comment: Just about everyone says "milkman" irrespective of the sex. For these purposes it can be considered sex-neutral.

Comment: @N.Virgo Because everyone uses it that way. No one is so hypersensitive as to make a fuss about it.

Comment: Also, the industry has changed dramatically. Milk delivery specifically limited to dairy products is the exception and not the norm any more. Similar remarks about _iceman_, which has not been an occupation for a long time.

Answer (score 6):

An informal word in use from my childhood was "Milko". The word was in use in Australia; I don't know about other parts of the world.

Comment: _Milko_ is used in British English also (and New Zealand) for a milkman and _OED_ has an example from The Daily Mail (London), from 1958. Although, the earliest citations are from Australian sources. _OED_ also provides this earlier original sense for _milko_: "_Chiefly British and Australian._ (A milkman's call) indicating that milk is available". Nice word,  upvoted.

Comment: That works but the caveat must be "it's informal".

Comment: Aussie English has a ton of words ending in o. Like **journo**. What I wouldn't give to visit there!

Answer (score 4):

An apt term is a *milk deliverer* and it is provided in [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_delivery#)'s "Milk Delivery" article also:

> Milk delivery is a delivery service dedicated to supplying milk. This service typically delivers milk in bottles or cartons directly to customers' homes. This service is performed by a **milkman, milkwoman**, or **milk deliverer**. (In contrast, a cowman or milkmaid tends to cows.)

[*Milkperson*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/milkperson) is a single word provided as nonstandard, rare by *Wiktionary* but it sounds rather awkward.

[*Milkie*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/118466#eid36872207) is listed in *OED* as an uncommon British slang word for a milkman or a milk-boy. Also (rarely): milk. The earliest citation is from 1886 per *OED*.

A thoughtful thought from Showerthoughts subreddit of [*Reddit*](https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/80vzkc/milkman_doesnt_have_a_genderneutral_counterpart):

> "Milkman" doesn't have a gender-neutral counterpart because it stopped being a viable career before the gender neutral movement.

Comment: In all my born days, I never saw (in a movie) a milkwoman. milkperson is frankly ridiculous. In fact, the entire exercise is anachronistic since there are no milkmen anymore anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional terms would have included **milk seller** and *milk carrier*. I'll focus on the first. OED, "[milk, n.1 and adj.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/118437)":

> milk seller  n.
>
> 1600   J. Pory tr. J. Leo Africanus Geogr. Hist. Afr. iii. 132   Next vnto them stand the milke-sellers.
>
> 1857   T. H. Lewin Let. 19 Nov. in Lewin Lett. (1909) II. v. 175   His companion is a milk-seller with..a brass vessel of milk in his hand.
>
> 1909   Daily Chron. 3 June 6/4   The dairy farmer, but more especially the milk seller, has already been prepared for drastic changes in the practice of his work.
>
> 1984   Pacific Affairs 57 151   This is an ethnographic and historical study of the village of Phulia Tola near Patna, populated almost entirely by Gowallas, traditionally cow-keepers and milk-sellers.

You can see the Library of Congress has titled an image of a "[man on horseback carrying basket with containers of milk](https://www.loc.gov/item/89708757/)" a **milk seller**. Cornelis Dusart (1660-1704) has a piece titled "[The Milk Seller](https://artuk.org/discover/artworks/the-milk-seller-33149)" that features someone who travels around carrying milk. And, similarly, one can find advertisements and other texts written using the term, like this one from 1916 in *The Dairy* ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Dairy/7yA3_rOaxYEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22milk%20seller%22&pg=PA63&printsec=frontcover)), which mentions deliveries:
[image]

Comment: Is it still too early for eight maids a-milking? :)

Answer (score -1):

For a gender-neutral term you can use "dairy supplier".

[image]

Comment: Only problem is that a dairy supplier is not a milkman.   https://www.thinkusadairy.org/applications/supplier-search/Results?CategoryID=67

Comment: I agree. Actually there is no way out of this. People have to agree to use only gender neutral terms. Take for example "postman". If you are considering degendering "postman" or such similar words, there are many different ways to do that as evidenced in this answer ( https://english.stackexchange.com/a/76148/397404 )  and other answers to this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76147/fisherman-fisherwoman-and-gender-neutral-forms

Comment: There is this nifty guide how to degender gendered words https://www.teenvogue.com/story/how-to-use-gender-neutral-words

Comment: I haven’t looked at the links but *xxxx delivery person* is the go-to in my experience. mail, milk, package, pizza…

Comment: I realise this is subjective but, in BE, I have never heard the phrase "dairy supplier" and I would assume that it mean someone who supplied milking machines. etc., and/or cattle food to dairies.

Comment: When in doubt, listen to native speakers (a number of them). "Dairy" in south Asia mean "milk and milk products"; "dairy farm" means "a farm where production of milk and milk derivatives is done". "Dairy supplier" would mean milk supplier, "dairy farm supplier" would mean a supplier to the dairy farm in south Asia.

Comment: No one would use the term "dairy supplier" for a person who delivers the milk to their home. "Milkman" may be considered sex neutral.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if I am correct or not; however, I'm fairly certain that the etymology of the word "man" denotes any human being. Seen in "manslaughter" and I would assume "milkman" as well. I might also be completely politically incorrect, but the etymology seems to support my statement (maybe). If I am wrong please do inform me, because I would like to be proven correct or not

Comment: It's possible, but I would need to see evidence that a woman selling or delivering milk was called a "milkman" unironically. Otherwise the OED definition clearly says that a milkman is "a man who sells or delivers milk," and that seems unambiguous.

Comment: If it can't be used for a group of women it's not gender neutral. "Man" isn't really ("she's one of the men who…" sounds mismatched to me), as do words like "maidenman" which hail from the Old English period when "-man" was truly gender neutral. Can you back up your suggestion with current usage? (See also [etymological fallacy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy#:~:text=An%20etymological%20fallacy%20is%20committed,present%2Dday%20meaning%20is%20invalid.))